# Cordova Android not sending AJAX request

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I have developed an app using Cordova and mainly developed it by testing IOS first. I have now published the app on the App Store and now want to publish it onto the google play store.

I have been testing the app via android studio and can't get past my login page. When I fill the form and submit it no AJAX request is made to check my login credentials and log me in.

I am using the android studio profiler to check if a request is made and I can't see one. I have added logging before the Ajax request but after the form is submitted and that is working.

After looking through multiple forums I still can't seem to get it working. I have added the white list plugin, I have setup CORS correctly because I had to do this to get it working for IOS.

Here is my config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="id" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Title</name>
    <description>
        description
    </description>
    <author email="email" href="http://cordova.io">
        Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
        <config-file parent="NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>Background location tracking is required to notify you when you enter a location offering deals</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>Background location tracking is required to notify you when you enter a location offering deals</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>Background location tracking is required to notify you when you enter a location offering deals</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSMotionUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>Device motion updates help determine when the device is stationary so the app can save power by turning off location-updates</string>
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#262262" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" spec="~2.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geofence" spec="^0.7.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-background-geolocation-lt" spec="^3.7.0">
        <variable name="BACKGROUND_MODE_LOCATION" value="&lt;string&gt;location&lt;/string&gt;" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-cocoalumberjack" spec="~0.0.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-qrscanner" spec="~3.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~4.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" spec="~0.9.0-beta.2" />
</widget>
```

Here is the AJAX code which doesn't seem to make any requests.

```
$("#login_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'login-url',
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data) {
            storage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token) // Pass a key name and its value to add or update that key.
            window.location.href = "deals.html";
        },
        error: function(httpObj, textStatus) {
            if (httpObj.status == 401) {
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Please try again using the correct credentials.',
                    alertDismissed,
                    'Incorrect Details',
                    'Try Again'
                );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: If you have an Android Device, you can enable USB debugging and check xhr requests in chrome or the new edge browser in PC. You'll get more clarity

Comment: Thank you, I did that and can now see the following error in the console - ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED. Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: While your device is connected to the pc, Try making an xhr request right from the console, to a normal URL, like `http://google.com` and check whether there's really Internet issue or there's an issue with your URL.

Comment: I get the same error when I made an AJAX GET request to https://google.com

Comment: In config.xml, under `<platform name="android">` add this tags `<config-file target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  
        </config-file>`

then build or run for android again and check if you are able to access Internet

Comment: I tried adding that bit now my build is failing with the following error - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  /Users/lukerayner/Documents/cordova-projects/stockport/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml:54: error: unbound prefix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217602/discussion-between-shaikh-amaan-fm-and-lukerayner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In config.xml, under `<platform name="android">` add this tags

```
<config-file target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">             
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />           
</config-file>
```

then build or run for android again and check if you are able to access Internet